# Ruby 2.7.4 Net Constant Warnings

Tags: ruby, rbenv, net-http

I'm getting repetitive warnings upon running a `ruby` script in a `crontab`, as well as manually in the terminal.

```
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:208: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
/Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:504: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
```

I've changed the script to either use `net/http` or `Faraday`, the latter I'm assuming requires the first.  Having seen this behaviour before recently and way back, this is a reload of the `net` gem, which is part of the `core` if I am correct.  I'm just not sure why it's reloading.

I'm using `rbenv` to juggle `ruby` versions for a couple of reasons, and that won't change.  My shebang is `#!/Users/rich/.rbenv/shims/ruby` but my `ruby` version is a bit different:

```
$ which ruby
==> /Users/rich/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/ruby

$ ruby -v
==> Ruby version: ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm64-darwin21]
```

This slight difference from the `shebang` and requested versions of `ruby` might be the issue.  I have many scripts that rely on that `shebang`, which points to the current `rbenv` version, which is what I want.  I change versions from time to time and don't want to hard code that instruction.

Is there a way I can see why this is happening?  How can I make these go away?  How can I stop reloading `core` gems that are already loaded?

Answer (score 6):

I had to add the following 2 lines to the `Gemfile` to finally eliminate the all the warnings:

```rb
gem 'net-http'
gem 'uri', '0.10.0'    # force the default version for ruby 2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bundler` was the culprit with some dependency issues and reloading various versions on top of previous `Gemfile.lock` versions...something like that.  Update this way:

```
bundle update --bundler
```

Comment: I've removed my previous answer. It seems like updating to a newer version of bundler that supports the default gems is the right solution

Comment: This did not work for me. The deleted answer from @amcvitty however did. Simply adding `gem "net-http"` to my `Gemfile` fixed this issue. My `bundler` was already updated as well.

Comment: @aarona What `version` of `Ruby`?  There were some versions recently that were heavy on these warnings.

Comment: @Rich_F `ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.7.2p137`

Comment: Also for reference the `net-http` gem installed is version `0.2.2`

Comment: That version might be the noisy culprit.  People started to complain this was happening for deprecated methods, etc.